# Finitely continuous fibrant replacement functor for localization of simplicial presheaves with projective model structure

Tags: higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories, simplicial-presheaves

Let $C$ be a model category given by generators and relations [in the sense of Dugger](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dugger%27s+theorem) (that is, $C$ is a left Bousfield localization of a global projective model model structure on simplicial presheaves on a small category $K$).

> Does $C$ have a fibrate replacement functor that preserves finite limits?

As far as I understand, in the case when $C$ is just the category of simplicial presheaves, then the functor $[K^\mathrm{op}, \mathrm{Ex}^{\infty}] \colon[K^\mathrm{op}, \mathrm{sSet}] \to [K^\mathrm{op}, \mathrm{sSet}]$ is the desired one (and [it also has other remarkable properties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324738/why-is-kans-ex-infty-functor-useful)).

But in the case of localization, I have so far only found a [mention](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+simplicial+presheaves#fibrant_objects) that there is something about ∞-stackification in HTT 6.5.3 and viewing it has not helped me yet.

Comment: Is there any reason to expect this to be true? (There is one obstruction I can think of: if finitary products are not homotopical then there cannot even be a fibrant replacement functor that preserves finitary products.)

Comment: In the case of ∞-toposes modeled by the local projective model structure, the existence of such a fibrant replacement functor can be deduced from the explicit construction of the associated ∞-sheaf given by the Verdier hypercovering theorem.